# How to show month data in the same presentation of vertical week list for mobile for Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

for full Calender jquery, in desktop view showing default view month i want same month data in vertical view list for responsive view. if any one click on arrow then it will showing result month wise. 
i have found this plugin
http://fiddle.jshell.net/danwoods/gyr2doxr/

but it showing vertical week list wise data i need by month

Comment: what have you attempted?